# FermionSpinSum in FeynCalc

Tags: physics, feyncalc

I have to evaluate the spin chains as described in the following PSE [question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/578489/evaluating-the-modulus-squared-of-a-spinor-chain-with-different-number-of-spinor).

To that end, in FeynCalc, I have done the following:

```
diag1 = U[k2, Me].V[k3, Me]*U[k1, Me].U[p1, MMu];
diag2 = U[k1, Me].GA[mu].V[k2, Me]*V[p1, MMu].GA[mu].V[k3, Me];

Intterm = 
 FermionSpinSum[diag1*ComplexConjugate[diag2]]// Contract // 
  FullSimplify
```

To which I get the result also explicit in the PSE question.

I was not sure if this was correct, so I made the following test with FermionSpinSum:

```
FermionSpinSum[SpinorU[k1,MA].SpinorUBar[k1,MB]]
```

which resulted in

```
Gamma.k1+MB
```

So that the completeness relation implemented by FeynCalc gives the same result independent of the mass of the first spinor. How does one circunvent that (or is it simply correct)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, your input is incorrect, as there are no `U` and `V` symbols in FeynCalc. The correct code would be

```
diag1 = SpinorUBar[k2, Me].SpinorV[k3, Me]*
   SpinorUBar[k1, Me].SpinorU[p1, MMu];
diag2 = SpinorUBar[k1, Me].GA[mu].SpinorV[k2, Me]*
   SpinorVBar[p1, MMu].GA[mu].SpinorV[k3, Me];

Intterm = 
 FermionSpinSum[diag1*ComplexConjugate[diag2]] // DiracSimplify
```

which yields

-

16
⁢

(


k1


*⁢
·
⁢

p1*



)

⁢

(


k2


*⁢
·
⁢

k3*



)



+

8
⁢
Me
⁢
MMu
⁢

(


k1


*⁢
·
⁢

k2*



)


-

8
⁢
Me
⁢
MMu
⁢

(


k1


*⁢
·
⁢

k3*



)


+

16
⁢

Me
2

⁢

(


k1


*⁢
·
⁢

p1*



)


-

16
⁢
Me
⁢
MMu
⁢

(


k2


*⁢
·
⁢

k3*



)


+

8
⁢

Me
2

⁢

(


k2


*⁢
·
⁢

p1*



)


-

8
⁢

Me
2

⁢

(


k3


*⁢
·
⁢

p1*



)


+

16
⁢

Me
3

⁢
MMu

As far as your question on Physics.SE is concerned, although you didn't specify what process you are calculating, it appears that you have Majorana particles involved (assuming that the amplitudes are correct). In this case the spin sum formulas alone are indeed insufficient to turn the spinor chain products into a trace. You also need to transpose some of the chains, cf. e.g. Section 3.3 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2001.04407.pdf.

`FermionSpinSum` does this automatically, unless the option `SpinorChainTranspose` is set to `False`.

Comment: Sorry about the mistake. What happens is that I make the definitions U[p_, m_] := Spinor[p, m]; V[p_, m_] := Spinor[-p, m]; in every notebook and, to write the question, simply copied the lines from it. Actually, the doubt from this question is simply solved by the physically obvious fact that if the 4-momentum of two particles are equal (in the same frame) then their masses are also identical (which I realized shortly). Thank you for your answer regarding the transposition of the chains, though! It confirmed what I was guessing and calculating but couldn't find any references about.